# Robotic tests should be independent

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, robotium

So i recently started using Robotium for the first time and noticed after some time that they are Executed in an alphabetical order. This made some test not work, because i needed the "introduction" of my app to be finished and than start other tests.

Since i have never used Automated tests before, im not sure how to write the tests right now. Should all the test cases ALWAYS be independent from each other?

This would mean in my case, that the flag for the introduction should be set false for some tests and true for other tests programmatically.

Or is it also right to assume that one test case has been Executed before another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. You should always build tests so they can run independently. Also take note to ensure you have a rollback process after running your tests. Otherwise the next time they might not run.

There is a lot to consider when writing automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. All tests should always be independent from each others. That way your sure that another test is not the reason for the failing test case.